# Get selected character in shell with mouse

Tags: linux, shell, console, mouse, termux

I'm curious about how different codes are written. And when i started to use Termux, i am with a dude:

How text editors like Vim can get what character you have selected to write after that?

Is it possible without using external libraries in low level languages like C or C++?

I am reading the code of Nano but it use external libraries to do that.

Comment: Considering many libraries are written in C then the technical answer to your question is yes - you just have to implement the same or similar functionality as those external libraries.

Comment: But how do those libraries do it? I've been looking and nowhere do they explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve such low level tasks using **termios.h** in C.
you should simply disable some of default shell features using functions in **termios.h** header file then use escape sequence to move the cursor and set/get characters. then you can make buffers and store or edit them how you like.

take a look at [this](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/index.html) guide. you will learn to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

In general, terminal emulators (following the old hardware terminals) are output devices, and provides little ability to query what is actually being displayed. The 'termios.h' will not provide lot of help. Some libraries (like curses) provide better control over the output, but relatively little ability to query what is on the screen.

Most code that know perform operation on the screen (e.g., vim, emacs) will keep track of what is being displayed on the screen, and what is the cursor position (or the selected area region), and use both pieces of information to perform the editing.

A special case is software that uses GUI frameworks (GTK, Qt, ...). They text widgets will provide API to query/set the displayed data, the selected data, etc. This API is provided based on copy of the data that is stored in the application.